# Blender auto rotates models unnecessarily during animations

Tags: animation, rigging

https://gyazo.com/9a420a0c0df9839ed3dfb600218b2876
https://gyazo.com/e7f6ba73ed6134588f4751b0d9d0c69a
The 2 gifs showed above, should make the problem easier to understand, since I know it sounds pretty weird just reading the title. This is supposed to be a "Spin-Move" from basketball, and with the video, you can notice that at the end of the animation, the model could've just normally resolve into the standing pose, but Blender just makes it turns an extra 180 in a complete opposite angle. I don't know if it's the problem of my rig, but this happens when I'm trying to do some spinning, turning, rotating animations, with the ball or the main rig. At first, I just roughly worked around it, but this time, I can even do that. Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This is about animation curves and how they work. You can do 2 things: use quaternions instead of Euler angles or use Discontinuity filter to clear these gaps. For Discontinuity filter, open graph editor and click Key ⇾ Discontinuity (Euler) filter

[image]

Quaternions are different from Euler angles. Then Euler angles repeats every 360 degrees, which means you have to deal with offsets on each turn, quaternions have no repeats, so you will not face this problem using quaternions.

[image]

Comment: I've tried the methods you've provided, my meshes and rigs was already using Quaternion, and I also tried to use the discontinuity filter, but it always shows that there's no F-Curves to be fixed, is there something that I did wrong? Sorry, but I'm fairly new to this :(